# How to fix "missing keymap" problem in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, keymapping

**The Event log shows this message - "*Cannot find keymap "Windows Proper Redo"*".**
Also, please explain about what is **keymap** here.
I have been searching the solution for so long on google, YouTube and stack overflow too. But did not find a proper answer.
Advance thanks to people who will solve this problem!

[image: missing keymap message]

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009453080-Missing-Keymap-Cannot-find-keymap-Default-copy-). I tested it and it works:

> Looks like, you have "Default Copy" keymap selected as active in "config/options/keymap.xml" whereas no "Default Copy.xml" file really exists in "config/keymaps" directory. Please try the following workaround: navigate to "Keymap" settings, choose any other keymap (let's say Eclipse), press OK, then open Keymap settings again and select the one you have had before back (f.e. Windows of you have Windows machine).